# Interrupt 'Play' and start recording as soon as the user starts talking

Tags: twilio

I am programming a conversational IVR which plays a prompt and records user answer. Then our service would transcript, analyze it and provide the corresponding answer, like an automated conversation.

As you can imagine, most of our users start talking before the message is actually finished. How can we set Twilio to stop the 'Play' command as soon as it hears the user talking?

That would make the conversation incredibly more interactive.

Thank you very much,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

If you are using [`<Gather>` and the recently launched speech recognition](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/twiml/gather) feature for it then you are able to [nest your `<Play>`](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/twiml/gather#nesting-rules) within the `<Gather>` and start listening as soon as the user speaks.

If you are using another method to record the user, perhaps `<Play>` followed by `<Record>`, then you cannot interrupt the `<Play>`. If this is the case, I recommend you investigate the latest abilities of `<Gather>`.